# PHP Date compare with data from a single field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quick question..

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to compare data from each date in a single field in a database like the following example:

```
field 1 |  field 2  |  field 3 | field 4
data 1     data 1      data 1    2015-09-03
data 2     data 2      data 2    2015-09-02
data 3     data 3      data 3    2015-09-01
data 4     data 4      data 4    2015-08-31
data 5     data 5      data 5    2015-08-30
data 6     data 6      data 6    2015-08-29
```

What I would like to do when php goes through the query I would like know how PHP can compare data between data say 2015-08-29 and 2015-08-30.

Comment: Appropriately enough; BETWEEN http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between

Answer (score 0):

Look into PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It has a lot of great features for comparing dates, doing general date arithmetic and outputting results in whatever format you need.

To get up to speed quickly google around for tutorials, here is one I like:

http://www.paulund.co.uk/datetime-php